# Cannot Install composer network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

**problem:**

I have created a Hyperledger fabric network with a six organization. After installing the composer network when I try to start composer network with giving me this error.

> × Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event

I tried a lot to find solution and I looks for the solutions given in previous stackoverflow questions regarding this matter.Can someone help me to solve this problem?.Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the composer logs (~/.composer/logs) and the peer logs for any error messages ? I'm guessing you are either using a Mac or Windows environment though ?

Comment: yeah, I am using windows environment.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a time difference between the Linux VM required by Docker to be able to run linux containers and your windows host. This can be confirmed by log messages in the peer and composer

Comment: dont use the windows enviroment please. I have tried aswell, wasted a good 10 hours on it. Download virtualbox and use an ubuntu OS. When following tutorials try to restart and then afterwards do those "Start.." or "execute..."  commands.